# Draw circuit of a transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

I have the following transfer function:

$$\frac{4}{s(s+0.5)}$$

How do I draw a circuit out of this function?

I don't have much electronics skill.

Comment: If you don't have electronics skill, then how do you know the specific transfer function?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: Actually, what I have to do is a PID controller for a specific plant, which I'm able to do. What I don't know, is how to draw the circuit of this plant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying partial fraction expansion to it, to get something in the form of

$$
\frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s+0.5}
$$

Choose \$A\$ and \$B\$ so that the partial fraction expansion equals your original transfer function. Now the first term can be represented as an integrator circuit, and the second term as an RC circuit. You'll also need a summation circuit that applies the required gain to each branch. There exist circuits with op amps that implement both integration and summation, and they're not hard to find.

There may be simpler circuits which also produce the desired transfer function, but the one outlined here is certainly a valid solution, if not the simplest one.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with a 1/s and a 4/(s+0.5) (Sorry I don't know how to format). But shouldn't they be multiplying? On this case, could I just have them in series? Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Bj8.png

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's the right answer. You'll need to equate my equation to yours and do the algebra. It's simple, but not as simple as you think given your answer.

Comment: Please ignore the values of the resistors and capacitors, I'm only looking for how to connect the two parts.

Comment: Although the circuit that corresponds to my transfer function would be different, the circuit in your figure would also work, but is something closer to your original equation. Now you just need to do some circuit analysis to figure out how to pick the values to match your exact transfer function above.

Comment: If my circuit would work then I'm going with that since it's easier for me to understand and get to the values I need.

One last question tho. I have a controller for this system, so I supposed I'll need a summation circuit for my input + the feedback?

Comment: If this is a closed loop PI controller then yes, you'll need a subtractor to produce the input to the PI controller. Note it's a subtractor: you want negative and not positive feedback.